# Converting time-stamps in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, timestamp

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74083683/19323948), I have the following dataframe:

```
              START_POINT   END_POINT   DURATION

island Stage            
1   SLEEP-S0    00:32:03    00:42:33    630.0
2   SLEEP-S1    00:42:33    00:45:03    150.0
3   SLEEP-S0    00:45:03    00:46:03    60.0
4   SLEEP-S1    00:46:03    00:48:33    150.0
5   SLEEP-S2    00:48:33    00:50:03    90.0
... ... ... ... ...
127 SLEEP-S2    09:32:03    09:39:03    420.0
128 SLEEP-S0    09:39:03    09:39:33    30.0
129 SLEEP-S1    09:39:33    09:40:03    30.0
130 SLEEP-S2    09:40:03    09:48:03    480.0
131 SLEEP-S0    09:48:03    NaN NaN
```

However, I want to convert the times here into times (in float or int) starting from t = 0. For example, this is what I want:

```
               START_POINT   END_POINT  DURATION

island Stage            
1   SLEEP-S0    0                630    630.0
2   SLEEP-S1    630              780    150.0
3   SLEEP-S0    780              840    60.0
4   SLEEP-S1    ...             ...     ...
5   SLEEP-S2    ...             ...    ...
... ... ... ... ...
```

and so on. Can someone please help?

Comment: seems like you're looking for [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)? e.g. `df["start"] = df["DURATION"].cumsum().shift().fillna(0)` and `df["end"] = df["DURATION"].cumsum()`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Do you want to convert this into an answer so that I can accept? I can also edit and include your answer in my question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```py
df["start"] = df["DURATION"].cumsum().shift().fillna(0)
df["end"] = df["DURATION"].cumsum()

df
Out[5]: 
                START_POINT END_POINT  DURATION   start     end
island Stage                                                   
1      SLEEP-S0    00:32:03  00:42:33     630.0     0.0   630.0
2      SLEEP-S1    00:42:33  00:45:03     150.0   630.0   780.0
3      SLEEP-S0    00:45:03  00:46:03      60.0   780.0   840.0
4      SLEEP-S1    00:46:03  00:48:33     150.0   840.0   990.0
5      SLEEP-S2    00:48:33  00:50:03      90.0   990.0  1080.0
127    SLEEP-S2    09:32:03  09:39:03     420.0  1080.0  1500.0
128    SLEEP-S0    09:39:03  09:39:33      30.0  1500.0  1530.0
129    SLEEP-S1    09:39:33  09:40:03      30.0  1530.0  1560.0
130    SLEEP-S2    09:40:03  09:48:03     480.0  1560.0  2040.0
131    SLEEP-S0    09:48:03       NaN       NaN  2040.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Reference this answer below
[How to standardize/normalize a date with pandas/numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036148/how-to-standardize-normalize-a-date-with-pandas-numpy)

You could standardize the array of timestamps and then you could multiply the standardized values by 10000000 to convert to an int.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I don't want normalized values in an interval.